# using "row" and "column" under Angular (Flexbox) creates a lot of vertical space between HTML input fields

Tags: html, css, angular

I am trying to have 2 input fields on the **same line**. To do this, I have been using Flexbox. I have noticed that when using `row` and `column` with Flex creates additional spacing as seen in the picture below:

[image]

Below is how the structure of the code is set up

[image]

**apidefs-disp.component.html**

```
<div class="flex-disp-apidefs-container">
    <div class="flex-disp-apidefs-list">

        <kdc-apidefs-list></kdc-apidefs-list> 
    </div>
    <div class="flex-disp-apidefs-form">
        <kdc-apidefs-form></kdc-apidefs-form> 
    </div>
</div
```

**apidefs-form.component.html**

```
        <div class="row">

            <!-- Name -->
            <div class="col">
                <div class="md-form">

                    <input required type="text" id="materialapidefsFormName" class="form-control"
                        aria-describedby="materialapidefsFormNameHelpBlock" mdbInput formControlName="name" />

                    <label for="materialapidefsFormName">Name</label>
                    <mat-error
                        *ngIf="apidefsForm.controls['name'].hasError('required') && apidefsForm.controls.name.touched">
                        Name is required
                    </mat-error>

                    <mat-error
                        *ngIf="apidefsForm.controls['name'].hasError('maxLength') && apidefsForm.controls.name.touched">
                        maximum Length is 25
                    </mat-error>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Description -->
            <div class="col">
                <div class="md-form">

                    <input required type="text" id="materialapidefsFormDescription" class="form-control"
                        aria-describedby="materialapidefsFormDescriptionHelpBlock" mdbInput
                        formControlName="description" />

                    <label for="materialapidefsFormDescription">Description</label>
                    <mat-error
                        *ngIf="apidefsForm.controls['description'].hasError('required') && apidefsForm.controls.description.touched">
                        Description is required
                    </mat-error>

                    <mat-error
                        *ngIf="apidefsForm.controls['description'].hasError('maxLength') && apidefsForm.controls.description.touched">
                        maximum Length is 50
                    </mat-error>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

[... snip ...]
```

**apidefs-disp.component.scss**

```
.flex-disp-apidefs-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
    flex: auto;
}

.flex-disp-apidefs-list {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; 
    //width:100%;
    flex:2;
}

.flex-disp-apidefs-form {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; 
    //width: 100%;
    flex:4;
}
```

**apidefs-list.component.scss**

```
NOTHING
```

**apidefs-form.component.scss**

```
.text-center {
    width: 100%;
}

 .flex-apidefs-form{
    display:flex;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 30px;
    background-color: var(--accent-lighter-color);

 }
```

**QUESTION**: how can I make the vertical distance between 2 sets of input fields smaller?

Any help, hints or advice would be greatly appreciated.

TIA

**ETA**
Currently getting following issue when attempting to copy code to Stackblitz (it seems to be referring to a product I paid for - not sure if paid-for product should be added to stackblitz)

[image]

Seeing how one can come about this issue ...

Comment: Can you please add stackblitz if possible, so that we can provide you best solution ?

Comment: Hi - does  stackblitz have Flexbox (and mdbootstrap) installed?

Comment: you can import it the same way as you are using in yout app, it will automatically install the dependencies.

Comment: You should never use row and column with Flex box because it adds unnecessary space as you just saw in your app. If you have row and column, try adding form-group class that will maintain the uniformity of your rows.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Since I am new to all of this, I went back to https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_forms.asp  I see the "inline" property - but - it is applied to an entire form. I wanted the "inline" effect for only 2 fields. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and changed the `display` for the class from 'flex' to 'grid'. It seems to be easier to use (at least one does not have to define `row` and `col` everywhere). Also, found out that the following class `md-form` had "extra padding" in it that was throwing the sizing off (I came across a similar case where the `html p tag` was having a side-effect (similar to the one mentioned above). So I did the following:

```
.grid-apidefs-form .md-form {
    margin: 0em;
    height: 4em;
}
```

to actually redefine it (by resetting the `margin` to 0) and setting a new height to 4em.

Everything is working now.